# Ho to upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 13.10

I have to upgrade an Ubuntu 12.04 to the last stable Ubuntu 13.10 but I have some doubts about how do it:

1) The first doubt is related to the fact that reading online seems that is not a smart thing update directly from 12.04 to 13.10 but I read that is better do it by steps:

from 12.04 to 12.10, then from 12.10 to 13.04 and finally from 13.04 to 13.10

Is it true?

2) Trying to perform the previous operation (the update from 12.04 to 12.10) following this official tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/QuantalUpgrades

I have followed the previous tutorial and I have activate the notification "For any new version" of the system but in the Update manager appear to me a strange thing, infact it say to me that is **available the new 14.04 release**

Reading online I see that **14.04** will be the new LTS and that this will be available in April of 2014, so what is this? is it a beta version or something like this?

I can't chose to upgrade to 12.10 or 13.10.

What can I do to upgrade my system to the last stable version?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to directly update 12.04 to 13.10 directly.It'll be better if you upgrade to 12.10 and then to 13.04 and eventually 13.10. The releases are made up so that you can go only from one version to another consecutively or from one LTS version to another LTS version. Otherwise it may result into buggy system and will ruin your experience of using ubuntu.

Now if you really want to install 13.10 you can download .iso from 
[here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and boot it to virtual machine via live usb or whatever you prefer.